# Exposing existing methods via the REST API

Tags: apex, apexrest, javascript-remoting

Given a class with a large number of methods (200+) because it acts as a fascade for the putrposes of Visualforce remoting, how would these same methods be best exposed to the REST API?

I'm thinking it either involves creating new Apex REST classes for all the various subsystems and exposing them via different endpoints, or, I expose one endpont with a single POST method which then works in a manner similar to the callable interface, and basically takes a method name as a parameter, and a JSON object as another, and uses the mother of all switch statements to invoke the appropriate method and return the response. As clunky as this is, I feel like it might be the simplest solution, as it's essentially re-implementing the facade that exists.

Am I missing an easier/cleaner/simpler way? Clearly the system processes these classes and generates specific functions for JavaScript when used with remoting but those are all platform implementation details that aren't accessible.

Comment: I'd be tempted to think through whether this VFRemoting API should be slavishly ported to a POST-based "REST" API, or whether you have, in fact, got objects and instances you are operating against - i.e. introduce a true REST API using PUT, PATCH, GET, DELETE and URIs that define the object or instance being operated on.

Comment: The "pass a method name as parameter and a JSON object as another" approach might work but isn't great for having a single entry point in your Apex code. I remember a project that had an implementation like this and it was a nightmare. Would recommend against this approach.

Comment: This is just my opinion, hence why I'm not answering the question, but I think you would be better off creating dedicated classes to call your existing code base, replicating the existing methods and their signatures. This at least isolates the calling code from the business logic code, which might seem more bureaucratic, but is more organized.

Comment: Not saying this is an answer but the [multiple invocables - single class solution](https://codefriar.com/universal-invocable) that codefriar and sfdcfox developed _might_ give you a solution - as invocables are accessible via REST (see Actions API). Downside is that error handling is a problem as the response object is not customizable

Comment: @PhilW Being built on remoting, and wanting to keep logic out of the UI at the time of inception, it's more of an RPC style setup than a natural fit for REST.

Comment: @cropredy I'd forgotten about that! I remember it looking interesting at the time. Funnily enough we have a standard repsonse object used on all the methods that wraps a generic `Object` with some basic additions like error messages.